# Ambiguities in De Bello Gallico 1.3.3

Tags: classical-latin, ambiguity, gaius-iulius-caesar, bellum-gallicum, praesens-historicum

There are a couple words and phrases which are ambiguous to me in Caesar's *De Bello Gallico, 1.3.3.* I'll reproduce the text, here, which I got from the [Perseus digital library](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0002%3Abook%3D1%3Achapter%3D3%3Asection%3D3).

> Ad eas res conficiendas Orgetorix deligitur. Is sibi legationem ad
>   civitates suscipit. In eo itinere persuadet Castico, Catamantaloedis
>   filio, Sequano, cuius pater regnum in Sequanis multos annos obtinuerat
>   et a senatu populi Romani amicus appellatus erat, ut regnum in
>   civitate sua **occuparet**, quod pater ante **habuerit**;
>
> For completing these things, Orgetorix is chosen. He takes it upon
>   himself to be an ambassador to the clans. On his journey he persuades
>   Casticus, the son of Catamantaloedes, a Sequanian, whose father had
>   held sovereignty over the Sequanis for many years, and had been named
>   a friend by the senate of the Roman people, that **he should seize**
>   sovereignty over his clan, which his father **had held** before;

**Ambiguities**

1. It's unclear to me whether the subject of *occuparet* is Casticus,
   or Orgetorix himself. That is, who should seize sovereignty? Is this made clear by context?
2. Should the verb *habuerit* be in the pluperfect, *habuerat*? Everything else describing the father is in the pluperfect, and it makes more sense here.

I appreciate any help in clearing up these ambiguities — thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question! I think it would be clearer to write "had been named a friend of the Roman people by the senate". The long description of the father is part of the governing clause with the indicative predicate *persuadet*, while the last relative clause is subordinate to the subordinate clause with the conjunctive predicate *occuparet*. I don't understand why everything is just the way it is, but that might play a role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sentence depends a bit on context. Nothing grammatically precludes Orgetorix from being the subject of *occuparet*, but if he were then the *sua* in *ciuitate sua* would have to refer to Orgeterix, too. Orgetorix would be saying to Casticus, "Since you father was king of *your* clan, you should come be king of *my* clan."

*habuerit* is in the perfect tense because it took place before *persuadet* while *occuparet* is imperfect because it's at the same time. We use the pluperfect in English in this case ("he persuades... that he should seize... because his father *had held*...) but that's just English. The present tense *persuadet* should be considered quasi-past tense since it is really describing past events ("historical" present). In Latin with the main verb in a past tense your choices in the subordinate clause are limited to imperfect or perfect subjunctive.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that the subordinate clause could take the present tense as well. But I guess you're saying that's not the case, correct? Regardless, I never thought that *habuerit* might be perfect subjunctive. I assumed it was a future perfect indicative. That was the source of my confusion. Looks like I should read up on subordinate clauses.

Comment: Regarding the first point, with Orgetorix, I wasn't aware that the possessive pronoun *suus* always refers to the subject. That clears up a lot. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Doesn't *consecutio temporum* allow only present and perfect conjunctive when governed by present tense? Since *occuparet* doesn't follow this rule, it might be an irreal conjunctive or something. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: You're right and that makes me realize I subconsciously glossed over the "historical present." _persuadet_ is present tense but is narrating something that really happened in the past so, as a historical present, and can be treated _either_ as primary sequence (following its form) _or_ as secondary sequence (following its sense). The _ut_ clause here is following secondary sequence.

Comment: Right, historical present is the crux here. You might consider editing the answer to address that.

Comment: Edited to clarify that point.

Answer (score 5):

I would add that `persuadeo` often takes a dative and `ut` (or `ne`) + subjunctive. "I persuade the dative to do (or not do) the subjunctive." Since `Castico` is in the dative right behind `persuadet` and `occuparet` follows later nicely filling out the period, the pattern matches perfectly and so it's hard not interpret this as a straight-up indirect command, with `Castico` therefore as the subject of `occuparet`.